# Runtime error when starting up iOS Firebase app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I never had this problem before but it all of a sudden occurred when I added deleting the user profiles in firebase user auth on my Swift UI app. What happens is when I start up the app a blank screen appears and after around 30 seconds a runtime error pops up in the terminal saying:

> 8.9.1 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

I am fairly new to this so I am not sure what kinda code to even start providing since the app is kinda big but I hope what I provide is somewhat helpful.

This is my main view:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class which manages user data:

```
class UsersManagerModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // observed classes
    @ObservedObject var fireViewModel = FirebaseViewModel()
    
    // shared info
    @AppStorage("email") var email = ""
    
    // variable used for user info
    @Published var firstName = ""
    @Published var lastName = ""
    
    func deleateProfile() {
        // remove user from storage
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("Users").document("\(email)")
        docRef.delete()
        
        // remove user from firebase auth
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            user.delete { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("success")
                    self.fireViewModel.loginPresented.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchUserData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        let docRef = db.collection("Users").document("\(email)")

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error", error ?? "")
                return
            }

            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let data = document.data()
                if let data = data {
                    print("data", data)
                    self.firstName = data["FirstName"] as? String ?? ""
                }
            }

        }
    }
    
}
```

I really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks. Once again the runtime error is:

> 8.9.1 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app

Comment: @user17979727 is the issue resolved?